# Trouble setting variables from form inputs. Radio and Text entries

Tags: javascript, forms

I am attempting to create an equation using people's pay rates and some other information from a from. However, I can't even get variables to set based on information from the form. The form includes 1 set of radio buttons and 2 text input forms.

```
    <form id="userInfo" action="" method="post">
<p>Pay Frequency: <select name="payFreqS">
            <option>Hourly</option>
            <option>Weekly</option>
            <option>Bi-Weekly</option>
            <option>Monthly</option>
          </select></p>
<p>Pay Rate:<input type="text" name="payRateS" value="0000.00">
</p>
<p>Cost of Item:<input type="text" name="costS" value="000.00">
</p>
</form>
<p><input name="submit" type="submit" class="btn" value="Submit" onclick="shouldIBuy()"/></p>
```

Javascript:

```
function shouldIBuy() 
{
    // attempt to find error with console statements
    console.log("How far can we get?");

    // setting variables for my function
    var payRate = document.getElementByIds("payRateS").value;
    var cost = document.getElementById("costS").value;

    // pay frequency variable
    var payFreq = document.forms[0].payFreqS;
    var i;
    for (i=0;i<payFreq.length;i++)
    {
        if (payFreq[i].checked)
        {
            payFreqVal = i;
        }
    }

    //more console.log statements to troubleshoot
    console.log(cost);
    console.log(payRate);
    console.log(payFreq);

    // setting what I hoped were strings to integers. 
    var payRateInt = parseInt(payRate);
    var costInt = parseInt(cost);
```

Comment: Execution probably stops at this typo:`var payRate = document.getElementByIds("payRateS").value;`

Comment: All you'd have to do is open the javascript console to see that.

Comment: Once that's fixed, you'll need to appreciate `name` and `id` are not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

There should be errors in your console because you are using the non-existent **getElementByIds**.

Answer (score 0):

I went back and broke it down to the very basic elements to figure out was going on. I was not referencing the right things. You were right. Thanks.